# xunit and System.Interactive.Async

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, xunit.net

I am trying to get the unit tests running in my .NET Core 1.0 solution. When I run an empty test it works fine. However, as soon as I try to create new instance of ApplicationDbContext the test fails with the following exception:

```
  System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Stack Trace:
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddQuery(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFramework(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetOrAdd>b__1(Int64 k)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
(2 more stack trace lines from my code)
```

Not sure why the System.Interactive.Async is needed at all, but I added it as dependency to my Tests project. The dll does not seem to be copied to bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0 folder on build, however. If I copy it there manually the effect it exactly the same. Any ideas what else can I do to get it working?

Comment: did you have added this to your test json file "portable-net45+win8"?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Having the same issue, but from my business logic class. I have portable-net45+win8 in my project.json frameworks imports.

Answer (score 7):

For me this error was being thrown because in my project.json I had correctly added:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-*",
```

to use core, but I hadn't removed this line which was further down my file between other dependencies:

```
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
```

Once I deleted that line, I got past this error.

Comment: Thanks @judgeja, you Saved my day :) +1 for you

Comment: Why does this happen? Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

I am using SQLite and Entity Framework Core. I was facing the below exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' or one of its dependencies
```

I have installed all necessary packages but it didn't solve.

There is a package named ***System.Interactive.Async (Ix Async)*** which can be installed through [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async)

Then my runtime exception was solved.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was an errant line

> EntityFramework.InMemory

**in addition** to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` in `project.json`. Once I deleted, it started working

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was same as mentioned above - i found forgotten *"`EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`"* dependency in linked project.

To investigate problem, I use my project's *`project.lock.json`*. There was 2 packets with *System.Interactive.Async.dll* - *Ix-Async/1.2.5* and *`System.Interactive.Async/3.0.0`*.

Then look which packet dependent from *`Ix-Async`* (still surfing in *`project.lock.json`*) and found that it was *EntityFramework.Core/7.0.0-rc1-final* . As there was no more packets that depends on *`EntityFramework.Core`* I realized that i have *`EntityFramework.Core`* in some of my own dependencies (one of my project's *`project.json`*)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue and I had to update binding redirect in app.config file to point to the appropriate version as shown below:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Interactive.Async" publicKeyToken="94bc3704cddfc263" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.3000.0" newVersion="3.0.1000.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Look at the oldVersion and newVersion in the above code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but, I think it may be a bug where you need to restart Visual Studio after you have updated NuGet packages such as System.Interactive.Async. I was running into the same error and tried adjusting  the version redirects in App.config. I couldn't get it to work. It kept giving me the error about not being able to load the assembly. It gave me the error even when downgrading the version to what it was looking for and rebuilding. I restarted Visual Studio and then it was all right. The only thing I can think of is maybe the test runner had something cached in memory. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score -1):

For those who may be newer, it might be as simple as restoring the NuGet packages at the project level.

In your solution, right click the project and click the Restore Packages option.